# Rails .each function to show ID of whats selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this segment of code,

```
<form>
  ID of event: <input type="text" name="ID" placeholder="E.g. 123">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<% @events.each do |ev| %>
```

How do i make this work? I'm wanting to have it so the id that is typed in the text box shows the related stuff from the events table in the rest of the page.

I was under the impression that it would be something like this `@events.id do |ev| ?`but i'm still a noob at rails :)

Thanks for any help Please be gentle!

Comment: Any reason why i got down-voted?

Comment: How did you come up with this code? It is incomplete.

Comment: I think you should use rails's `form_tag` or `form_for` not html forms. Also, where is submit button?

Comment: Look at the answer where i explain how i messed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i had done this all wrong!

i had to add this in my controller

```
  def index
    @events = Event.where(id: params[:id])
    @id = params[:id]
  end
```

and put this in to search for the ID

```
 <%= form_tag({controller: "event", action: "index"}, method: "get") do %>
          <%= label_tag(:id, "Input the ID to display:") %>
          <%= text_field_tag(:id) %></p>
          <%= submit_tag("Submit ID") %>
    <% end %>
```

Sorry for the confusion but i thought it best to add the answer on how i fixed it.